# Outlook rounded image with rounded background

Tags: css, image, outlook, email-templates

I'm trying to develop an email template. I need a rounded image with rounded background in outlook. Here is the code and the [outlook output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoTfi.jpg) which is not what I'm trying to develop.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">

<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                <!--[if mso]>
                <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://example.com" style="height:80px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:80px;" arcsize="50%" strokecolor="#EB7035" fillcolor="#EB7035">
                    <w:anchorlock/>
                    <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;">

                        <img style="width: 80px;height: 80px;border-radius: 50%; background-color: #e0f6fc;" width="80px" height="80px" align="center" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR13vYIvuNYydJxdMvpmCPXyqzDeUcJIxvdJV1T2GT9FgMyTTiGhw">
                    </center>
                </v:roundrect>
                <![endif]-->
                <!--[if mso]>
                    <img style="width: 80px;height: 80px;border-radius: 50%; background-color: #e0f6fc;" width="80px" height="80px" align="center" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR13vYIvuNYydJxdMvpmCPXyqzDeUcJIxvdJV1T2GT9FgMyTTiGhw">
                <![endif]-->
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

What I exactly want is a simple rounded box with border which there is a simple rounded image is inside that (center of the box). Any ideas ?

Comment: The first can be a VML but the second will have to be an image. We can not place VML inside VML. If you want it more rounded (from above example) i would say increase the width and height. The arc-size will change depending on your tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple and full-proof fix...
Create a rounded image and either include the background colour in the image or use VML to create the rounded colour.

Comment: What do you mean by vml ?

Comment: VML is the greyed out code you have in code in your original post. So set a border radius on the table cell or div for email clients other than Outlook and then use the <v:roundrect> code for Outlook.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try the code in this example - https://litmus.com/builder/32e80d7. Referenced from - https://litmus.com/community/discussions/6939-rounded-image-outlook. I haven't used or tested this, so it would be up to you to amend to work for your example and then test.

Comment: I've tried it. The output is different from what is shown there!

Comment: Well, there you. I would go with just making a simple rounded image and using that in your template(s).

Answer (score -1):

One solution would be to wrap your image in a div to crop the image into a circle with `border-radius: 50%` and `overflow: hidden`. Then wrap that div in another div to create the rounded background color. Here is some starter HTML and CSS, and you can adjust the color, padding, and border-radius to your liking.

HTML

```
  <div class="img-container">
    <div class="img_crop">
        <img src="your-image" alt="Logo">
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
    .img-container {
      width: 300px;
      padding: 40px;
      background-color: blue;
      border-radius: 130px;
    }
    .img_crop {
      border-radius: 50%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    img {
      width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: Outlook will not read a width on a div, border radius or overflow.

Comment: not effective because It's outlook and way different from simple HTML.